# Narrow a class property type with a method decorator

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a class which has a property that can be one of different types and has its type change in a method decorator, before the method is called.

Is there a way to have it so that when a specific decorator is used on a method, it narrows that property's type within that method?

Super contrived example:

```
function defaultName<This extends Foo & {name: string}, Args extends any[], Return>(
    target: (this: This, ...args: Args) => Return,
    context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext
) {
    return function (this: This, ...args: Args): Return {
        if (!this.name) this.name = 'Foo';
        return target.call(this, ...args)
    }
}

class Foo {
    name: string | null;
    constructor() {
        this.name = null;
    }

    @defaultName // When applied to the method, narroaw this.name's type to string
    greet() {
        console.log('Hey, Im', this.name.toUpperCase()) // Error, this.name is possibly "null"
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKbAIYgDZQHIYC2qAPACoAWMAzoqgB5SpjK0BicciAZIgN5giqAFyJqUAE4wwAcwC+AGkQBBCTNoMmLWhjABPANoBdJQCVUUEBLAA+ABQAoRM8RQMai6LtQq1UZRolADoQ93VRVXUASkQAXhtEc0trBScXCAQmRlEAYWwMamoAWQsKOGQAEVQMiQwoOAkczM0HGL405wkLKyRQSFgERG9ff19g0LU-FUmo0SSe-g6XZxhgIYBCHxogwWIYreodoTjEAHIOOFOAbiXlruSkNw8oIIgMbGxhwMQQoLDqKJLOQOYEOCD5QqIC6LZa7ERiSTSGSIAA+iDAOGwN2WGTA4gkIGgDTsbVuLgOR2IJwxH2xLlBywAAmhMDh8McAPQcxAAdQozEQGAADkLsDBUMhXFwfKhEMQfOUlIIJBI4BgAO6uXyU1CnWhQPRC2X1BFSWRLGRdCwkmHLdIIahwbCoILYOAyOynAASqD0SgAkoRTkoKXCgvUAKoi1CNAqoEkxLmIACiKoaIe1cMQNEQQrghRgACNsHpEAAiGnYMtAkEOIA)

My attempt to get this to work is the `Foo & {name: string}`, but no luck.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, it sounds like you're trying to mutate the class definition from a decorator which is currently [not possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881).

Comment: It's not exactly that kind of mutation but I also don't think it's possible; you'd need something like [`ThisType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) but it doesn't act on methods directly, only objects with methods.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thank you both for your inputs! I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe decorators can mutate a class's types.

There are many open discussions about this e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881